# Efficiently flipping instances of 1 to 0 in 2D Matrix with least moves

Tags: php, algorithm

What is the most efficient way of flipping binary values from 1 to 0 in a 2d array, travelling the matrix using the shortest distance possible?

e.g flip the following, and mention the path taken to get to all the 1s.

- The array has same width and length
- At the start, the algorithm will know WHICH coordinate positions have a 1 e.g below it will know 0:1, 1:0, 1:2 etc have a 1 to flip

{0 1 0 0 0 0}
{1 0 1 0 1 0}
{0 0 0 0 0 0}
{0 0 1 0 0 0}
{0 0 0 0 1 0}

I have tried using two for loops, but they unnecessarily traverse all rows and columns each time.

Is there a specific theory for this type of traversal? If I am given this I can look it up and do it.

I will be using PHP as implementation language.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: *I will be using PHP as implementation language.*: Then why tag Java and Javascript? language-spam is not liked on Stack Overflow, you'll just get more attention from multiple tags, and if your question is badly received you have just more negative attention

Comment: @Lino, I want input from ANY language, though I will be implementing in PHP, hence my tagging java, js and PHP developers.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right then you know on which places are 1's.
You could save those places in an array like this:
Given Array of all 0's and 1's:

```
{0,0,0}
{0,1,0}
{1,0,1}
```

Array, where the coordinates of the 1's are saved

```
arr = [{i:1, j:1}, {i:2, j:0},{i:2, j:2}]
```

then u could do following:

```
for(let i = 0; i < arr.lengt; i++){
arrWithAll0and1[arr[i].i][arr[i].j] = 0
}
```

So you just have to iterate over your small array with the positions of the 1's and not over the whole array with all 0's and 1's.

P.S.: I'm not familar with php so I wrote it as TS/JS-Code, but I'm sure you can change the syntax to php